# Nifi - Replace values

Tags: json, text, replace, apache-nifi, jolt

Good Afternoon!

I have a JSON with:

```json
{
  "cnpjemitente" : "48791685000168",
  "pedido" : "543306",
  "pedidocliente" : { },
  "emissao" : "20220912"
}
```

I need to replace the value `"pedidocliente: {}"` to:

```json
{
  "cnpjemitente" : "48791685000168",
  "pedido" : "543306",
  "pedidocliente" : null,
  "emissao" : "20220912"
}
```

Sometimes the value will come in the field, I just want to send null when it is empty with `'{}'`.

How can I do it this way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **modify-overwrite-beta** transformation spec within a ***JoltTransformJSON*** processor such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "pedidocliente": null
    }
  }
]
```

as you only need to change an individual attribute's value without affecting the others.

If it's the case that the value does not return always **`{}`**(*an empty object*), then rather use a **shift** transformation spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "pedidocliente": {
        "*": "&1.&"
      },
      "*": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Sometimes the value will come in the field, I just want to send null when it is empty with '{}'.